# eliminate 'Array' string While printing associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have following PHP code

```
    <?php
$myRoom = array(
                'Kitchen' => array('Dining Table','4 Chairs','Dishes'),
                'Bathroom' => array('Towel','Medicines','Shower Gel'),
                'Bedroom' => array(
                                'Bed' => array(
                                            'Legs' => 4,
                                            'Bedsheet' => 'woolen',
                                            'Blanket' => array(
                                                               'Winter' => 'Thick',
                                                               'Summer' => 'Thin',
                                                            ),
                                ),
                                  ),
                'Person' => 'Only Me',
                );
my_room($myRoom);

function my_room($params) {
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        yes_it_is(" <br /> ".$key." : ");
        my_room($value);
        yes_it_is($value." <br /> ");
    }
}

function yes_it_is($val) {
   echo $val;    
}
```

The functions below prints the string, and the output of the code looks like:

> Kitchen : 0 : Dining Table
>
> 1 : 4 Chairs
>
> 2 : Dishes Array
>
> Bathroom : 0 : Towel
>
> 1 : Medicines
>
> 2 : Shower Gel Array
>
> Bedroom : Bed : Legs : 4
>
> Bedsheet : woolen
>
> Blanket : Winter : Thick
>
> Summer : Thin Array Array Array
>
> Person : Only Me

How can I get rid of the 'Array' string that is printed with other values. Any other workaround would also be appreciated.

Edit:

I want to print only keys and values that was in associative array, not `Array` as string in output.

Edit2: Question updated as per Daedelus' suggestion

I changed my_room function as below:

```
function my_room($params) {
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            yes_it_is(" <br /> ".$key." : ");
            if (is_array($value))
                my_room($value);
            else
                yes_it_is($value." <br /> ");
    }
}
```

But still the output is:

> Kitchen : 0 : Dining Table
>
> 1 : 4 Chairs
>
> 2 : Dishes
>
> Bathroom : 0 : Towel
>
> 1 : Medicines
>
> 2 : Shower Gel
>
> Bedroom : Bed : Legs : 4
>
> Bedsheet : woolen
>
> Blanket : Winter : Thick
>
> Summer : Thin Array Array
>
> Person : Only Me

There are two `Array` printed after `Thin`

Edit3: Sorry my mistake, The accepted result works perfectly. While testing I had two functions together name `my_room` and `my_room2`, while testing with both the functions together `Array` was displayed, but when I commented out `my_room2` and only displayed `my_room` function as in the answer, it works perfectly. Sorry for any confusions caused, I was testing two functions together and the output was weird.

Edit4:

Based on the answers below, I changed it to good looking one line ternary operator like:

```
function my_room($params) {
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            yes_it_is(" <br /> ".$key." : ");
            is_array($value) ? my_room($value) : yes_it_is($value." <br /> ");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php ?

Comment: Fix your code so it can handle the deeper levels of your array, or add code to filter out those sub-arrays or otherwise convert them to printable strings.

Comment: @MarcB, any workaround/tutorial to achieve that would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change my_room to the following (to check if it's an array)

```
function my_room($params) {
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            yes_it_is(" <br /> ".$key." : ");
            if (is_array($value))
                my_room($value);
            else
                yes_it_is($value." <br /> ");
    }
}
```

Comment: @JhilkeDai Please update your question code then under another header, because the above should have worked for you.

Comment: @JhilkeDai Well, I don't know what to tell you.  I just did a test with that code and it works fine.  What php version are you running on?

Comment: @Daedalus 5.4.6 the `Array` in other places like. after `Dishes` and `Gel` went away. There were 3 `Array` after `Thin`, now it shows two. I too really don't know why it is like that

Comment: @Daedalus I edited the question again, the answer is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to ignore arrays passed to the function:

```
function yes_it_is($val) {
   if (!is_array($val)) {
       echo $val;
   }
}
```

*Edit:* Wait, you are concatenating with `"<br />"` before, so this will not work. Better solution:

```
function my_room($params) {
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        yes_it_is(" <br /> ".$key." : ");
        if (is_array($value)) {
            my_room($value);
        } else {
            yes_it_is($value." <br /> ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function yes_it_is($val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
       print_r($val);
       //OR echo "<pre>"; print_r($val):
    } else {
       echo $val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`is_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) should do the trick:

```
function my_room($params) {
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {  
        yes_it_is(" <br /> ".$key." : ");
        if (is_array($value)) {
            my_room($value);
        }
        else {
            yes_it_is($value." <br /> ");
        }
    }
}
```

What happens otherwise..  you are trying to convert an array to a string, and that comes out as the string `Array`.  If you do a check before hand to make sure it is indeed an array, you won't get that error.  I also recommend you turn on error reporting, as well as read the [manual for arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php).